# Making column flag based on amounts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe of experiments, whether they won or not, and the amount of plans offered.

Each experiment_id can have many plans offered. I want to label the maximum plans_offered as 'More Plans' and any lower amounts 'Less Plans'. The assumption is that all experiment id's are redundant (not unique). How can I make this flag?

**EDIT**
I realized the above didn't make sense for my problem. I want a new flag that says More/Less Plans when the plans_offered number is neither the highest or the lowest.

Input

```
experiment_id   winner  plans_offered
1               1       3
1               0       1
2               1       3
2               0       7
3               1       6
3               0       5              
4               1       2
4               0       3
4               0       4
5               1       5
5               0       4
```

expected output

```
experiment_id   winner  plans_offered  flag
1               1       3              More Plans
1               0       1              Less Plans
2               1       3              Less Plans
2               0       7              More Plans
3               1       6              More Plans
3               0       5              Less Plans
4               1       2              Less Plans
4               0       3              More/Less Plans
4               0       4              More Plans
5               1       5              More Plans
5               0       4              Less Plans
```

Comment: Any reason why `experiment_id` `4` doesn't have *More Plans* ?

Comment: Just edited, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is the answer you want based on your explanation. I'm guessing you want to flag the maximum `plans_offered` for each `experiment_id` with `"More Plans"`. Here's one way you can do that:

```
for i in df.experiment_id.unique():
    
    max_plans = df.loc[df.experiment_id==i, 'plans_offered'].max()

    df.loc[
        (df.experiment_id==i) &
        (df.plans_offered==max_plans),
        'flag'
    ] = 'More Plans'

df.flag = df.flag.fillna(value='Less Plans')
```

I'm not totally sure why this process might be necessary though — I have a hunch there's a simpler way to get to your final endpoint than this, unless this dataframe is your actual final product.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the max `plans_offered` by `experiment_id` using `groupby.transform('max')` first and then assign `More Plans` to values that are equal to grouped max, `Less Plans` otherwise:

```
import numpy as np
is_max = df.plans_offered.groupby(df.experiment_id).transform('max') == df.plans_offered
df['flag'] = np.where(is_max, 'More Plans', 'Less Plans')

df
#    experiment_id  winner  plans_offered        flag
#0               1       1              3  More Plans
#1               1       0              1  Less Plans
#2               2       1              3  Less Plans
#3               2       0              7  More Plans
#4               3       1              6  More Plans
#5               3       0              5  Less Plans
#6               4       1              3  Less Plans
#7               4       0              3  Less Plans
#8               4       0              4  More Plans
#9               5       1              5  More Plans
#10              5       0              4  Less Plans
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `transform` then map

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('experiment_id')['plans_offered'].transform(lambda x : x ==x.max()).map({True:'More Plans',False:'Less Plans'})
df
    experiment_id  winner  plans_offered         new
0               1       1              3  More Plans
1               1       0              1  Less Plans
2               2       1              3  Less Plans
3               2       0              7  More Plans
4               3       1              6  More Plans
5               3       0              5  Less Plans
6               4       1              3  Less Plans
7               4       0              3  Less Plans
8               4       0              4  More Plans
9               5       1              5  More Plans
10              5       0              4  Less Plans
```

Update

```
g = df.groupby('experiment_id')['plans_offered']
cond1 = df['plans_offered'] == g.transform('max')
cond2 = df['plans_offered'] == g.transform('min')
df['new'] = np.select([cond1,cond2],['More Plans','Less Plans'],default = 'More/Less Plans')
df
    experiment_id  winner  plans_offered              new
0               1       1              3       More Plans
1               1       0              1       Less Plans
2               2       1              3       Less Plans
3               2       0              7       More Plans
4               3       1              6       More Plans
5               3       0              5       Less Plans
6               4       1              2       Less Plans
7               4       0              3  More/Less Plans
8               4       0              4       More Plans
9               5       1              5       More Plans
10              5       0              4       Less Plans
```

Comment: This is great. I just updated my question because I realized I need something else. Basically when the number is neither the highest or the lowest I want to flag it as More/Less plans. Do you know how to adapt your code to do this?